# Background Task to record time and write it into file in uwp application

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Toast notification have a "close button" in the upper right corner.I want to get the current time  when user click that "close button" and append the time in the text file in UWP application.

I have tried with  ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger while registering background task But in LifeCycleEvents in visual studio it does not shows any events and the code is executed without any error.

```
 builder.Name = "Sample";
     builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTaskGps.SampleBackgroundTask";
     builder.SetTrigger(new T ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger()); 

     BackgroundTaskRegistration taskRegistration = builder.Register();
```

and In manifest

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTaskGps.SampleBackgroundTask">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="System Event" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Is there any other way to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried with ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger while registering background task But in LifeCycleEvents in visual studio it does not shows any events

According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx):

> The debugger can trigger only those events that do not contain data, such as events that indicate a change of state in the device. You have to manually trigger background tasks that require user input or other data.

The [ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.toastnotificationactiontrigger) requires user to close the notification so it cannot be triggered by debugger. But actually it does work when you close the notification on the action center. The [notification official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications) has a scenario page about [HistoryChangedTrigger](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/ScenarioPages/Toasts/HistoryChangedTrigger) which register the `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger` and when notification in action center closed by user it will trigger a background task to update the badge of tile. Add writing file logic inside this background task will meet your requirements. Code like follows:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail;
    if (details == null)
        return;
    StorageFolder localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile tempfile = await localfolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(tempfile, "test time");
    ...
    taskInstance.Progress = (uint)details.ChangeType;
}
```

Pay attention that this trigger worked for notification closed from action center, closed directly when notification is pushing is not supported. You may custom a button in the notification content to try to interaction with user.  If you want to handle activation from a toast notification please reference [Handling activation from a toast](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/).

Comment: It is not triggering even though i close the toast notification and i want to get the title of the toast notification in the Run method.